# particular function with these properties?

Tags: functions

assume having a function $f_n(x)$ such that:

$\bigg\{ ^{\forall n \ odd \ \rightarrow f_n(x) = sign(x)} _{\forall n \ even \ \rightarrow f_n(x)=1}$

I need a function with these particular properties, I was wondering if you could help me find it and presumably show me how to, especially. I would be very grateful if you take a look at this

p.s. I don't know how to properly format the LaTeX bracket so that it looks like a system of equations.

Comment: What do you mean "you need a function with these properties"? Is the function you wrote not a function with those properties?

Comment: hyper-neutrino well yes, but what I need is to write such function algebraically.

Comment: Then you should clarify that - "I need a function" doesn't give enough details since you already have a function, it's just not what you want. Also, you can't get an algebraic sign function unless you guarantee $x\neq 0$. Please be more clear what operations are allowed and disallowed for it to be an "algebraically written function".

Comment: hyper-neutrino isn't zero even though? why wouldn't it count?

Comment: $x$, not $n$. Is $\sgn(x)$ algebraic according to your definition? If not, you have to use a hack like $\frac{|x|}{x}$ which doesn't work for $x=0$. This is why I say you _need_ to clarify what you want.

Comment: hyper-neutrino I see your point, if we use the $\frac{x}{|x|}$ it's obvious that it's not going to work, but looking at the definition found in english wikipedia, it includes 0 as an option, even if the definition of sign is not algebraic which may sound a bit hypocritical of me but, that doesn't bother me to be fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are working with a function $f_\bullet:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, i.e. with a function that assigns to each value of $n\in\Bbb N$ a function $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, therefore you would call that a *sequence* of functions in order to distinguish it from its values, which most would conisider *functions* in a more natural way. Anyways, assuming that the identities in $x$ are meant to hold for all $x\in \Bbb R$, there is not much room for guessing: $f_n$ must be the $\operatorname{sgn}$ function for $n$ odd and the constant $1$ for $n$ even. Most authors would just write $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n\text{ even}\\ \operatorname{sgn}x&\text{if }n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

But if you want a trick, you can go something like $$f_n(x)=\left(1-\left(n-2\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\right)\right)\cdot 1+\left(n-2\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\right)\operatorname{sgn}x=\\ =\frac{1+(-1)^n}2\cdot 1+\frac{1-(-1)^n}2\cdot\operatorname{sgn}x$$

I like to think of these tricks as things that certain people want more than anything in this world, until they are forced to use them. Then they don't want them anymore.

Comment: Thank you! it's very similar to the one I've come up with myself, I'm going to mark your question the correct solution and still leave my one :)

Comment: @Algoak Yours is sgn for n even and 1 for n odd, which is not what you asked. If you adapt the idea to the actual question, you obtain my second expression, more or less.

Comment: Oh damn I could I've been so stupid- I'm sorry I really didn't notice that o_o